# Android In App purchase example without transactions from Google checkout?

Tags: android

Is there any app purchase example without cut off any charges from google checkouts account?? I mean Totally free app purchase demo for android...

Comment: If you are referring to going "around" Google's in app purchase, and using your own, then if you plan to publish to Market you would be in violation of their TOS.

Comment: @jack how to get publish key??

Comment: Huh?! Publish key? Please re-word your question.